# Why does the getBoolean always return default?

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I'm using SharedPreferences to store the value of multiple checkboxes and some strings, and it's doing well. When I try to use it to store the value of a switch it doesn't work, and keep getting the default value.

I initialize like this

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
SharedPreferences prefs;
```

I put this on "onCreate"

```
editor = getSharedPreferences(FirstStart.MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
prefs = getSharedPreferences(FirstStart.MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

And then I'm testing it on the "onClick" event of the switch (I'm using toasts to test)

```
public void clickSwitchAlarm(View view) {
    editor.putBoolean("swAlarma", swAlarm.isChecked());
    Toast.makeText(MainMenu.this, "isChecked() value: " + swAlarm.isChecked(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //Toast.makeText(MainMenu.this, "getBoolean value: " + prefs.getBoolean("swAlarma", false), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

When I check the "isChecked()" value it works fine, but when I check the SharedPreferences stored value it shows the default.

Does anybody know what's happening here? Thank you!

(Working with API15)

Comment: <Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:text="Alarma: "
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="136dp"
        android:onClick="clickSwitchAlarm" />

Comment: `editor.commit()` at the end

Comment: or call `editor.apply()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After putting the value inside the editor, you **must** confirm the operation by calling `commit()` or `apply()` method`s :

```
editor.commit();
//or
editor.apply();
```

Otherwise your operation will not be validated and the value will not be saved.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't notice!